# Why $|e^{i(n+1)x}| + |1| = 2$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Why $|e^{i(n+1)x}| + |1| = 2$? I was studing the partial sums of $sin(x)$ for the Dirichlet's test and didn't understand this part.

Comment: Because $|e^{it}|=1$ if $t$ is a real number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that 
$$
e^{iy}
$$
for $y$ with zero imaginary part is a point on the unit circle in the complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you know $|1| =1$.  $\left| e^{i(n+1)x}\right| = 1$ if $n$ and $x$ are real: see [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).